# How many Portlet Context objects are created for differnt portlets are configured in Single Portlet application

Tags: java, portlet, portal, jsr286

I am new to Portlet Application development, I am having one doubt regarding PortletContext object.  If multiple portlets are configured in single portlet application then How many PortletContext objects are created per PortletApllication. i.e either PortletContext object is created per each portlet in PortletApplication or single PortletContext Object for entire PortletApplication.

Thanks & Regards
Mini.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an answer to your question it will be in the JSR 286 specification.

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr286/

Otherwise if it's not stated in there, then it's up to the portlet container to decide on how many PortletContext objects to create. Which essentially means that you shouldn't make any assumptions about the number of objects. I don't know the motivation for this question but my suggestion is to make your code independent of the number of PortletContext objects.